# How to detect orientation change on mobile browser?

Tags: android, mobile, browser

Nothing is working on my phone I was testing Firefox and Chrome mobile and none of the above work:

```js
  var resize = throttle(() => matrix.resize(width(), height()), 1000);

  window.addEventListener('resize', resize);

  const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(resize);
  resizeObserver.observe(canvas);

  const portrait = window.matchMedia('(orientation: landscape)');

  if (screen?.orientation) {
    screen.orientation.addEventListener('change', orentation);
  }

  const pre = document.createElement('pre');
  document.body.appendChild(pre);

  function log(message) {
    pre.innerHTML += message + '\n';
  }

  function orentation() {
    debugger
    if (e.matches) {
      log('landscape');
    } else {
      log('portrait');
    }
  }
  
  window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function() {
    alert(screen.orientation);
  }, false);
```

Nothing is executed when I rotate my phone (Samsung Galaxy S21 with USB Debugging enabled).

So the question how can I detect the orientation change? I want to rotate my phone into landscape mode and on my mobile browser I want to change something when it triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If none of the events for orientation change are triggered it's probably that your phone has fixed orientation. This was my case I had it fixed for portrait, toggling autorotation to make it work and all events are now triggered including resizing on Android.